# White Screen of Death upon installation of any OS

Tags: installation, white-screen

I am trying to reformat my Alienware M15x laptop which has an aftermarket graphics card installed (NVidea Geforce 675m).

I have tried to install Windows 7 Ultimate (which was previously on it), Windows 7 Professional, Windows 8 Professional, and Windows 8.1 Professional, all which were burnt using ImgBurn onto DVD-RW's. Everything goes fine until it past the unpacking stages of the installation and it restarts and shows the Windows loading symbol. This is when the screen goes completely white (with no cursor) and I cannot do anything.

To add to that, if I try to run in safe mode, it says "Setup cannot complete in safe more click okay to restart and continue setup".

P.S.

I know it is not the ISO's because they come from DreamSpark and I just reformatted the computer I am currently using to ask this question with an ISO burnt onto a disk two days ago.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I actually do have an exam, today @DavidPostill

Comment: I guess the point of the edit was, well, you might not get it to work by then. Anyways, how are you installing it? From CD or live USB? And when saying "no matter which OS", which OSes have you actually tried? Also, what is "the first part of the installation"?

Comment: I get your point, I'll update the Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue after re-seating everything on the motherboard. One of the RAM cards was not fully inserted. So for future reference, if you ever come across this issue. Make sure your RAM cards are seated correctly.